# Kotlin: can I get an object inside an object using variable whose value is the name of an object?

Tags: kotlin

Usually I use JavaScript, and in it you can have this:

```
var objectVar = "myOtherVariable";

var someObject = {
    myVariable: "something",
    myOtherVariable: "something else"
}

// writes out 'something else'
console.log(someObject[objectVar])
```

Is it possible to do something like this in kotlin?

For instance, if you have

```
val myVar = "a"
object someObject{
    var a: MutableSet<ImageView> = mutableSetOf()
    var b: MutableSet<ImageView> = mutableSetOf()
}
```

Can you, in any way, get to the `someObject.a` by using `myVar`?

### Edit

Since the general consensus is it should not be done, even if possible, I managed to change the logic so I don't have to use it.

Comment: If I understand what you mean correctly, then I believe the answer is, "no".

Comment: Possible? Yes, with a heaping pile of [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and a bit of knowledge of how Kotlin compiles your code on the JVM. A good idea? Absolutely not.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes, reflection can be used for certain things, and perhaps that is what the OP is looking for. Though as I understood the question, they wanted to do something like `SomeObject.myVar` (where `myVar` references the string `"a"`), and have that "directly" resolve to the same thing as `SomeObject.a` (or `SomeObject.b` if `myVar` was changed to reference the string `"b"`, even if done dynamically).

Comment: As Silvio says, this is rarely a good approach in a strongly-typed language like Kotlin.  While it's possible (using reflection), you lose type safety and type inference; you lose discoverability and IDE completion and refactoring; you lose performance; and you lose readability and conciseness.  If you're coming from a different kind of language, it's only natural to try to transate the programming patterns you already know — but in the long run it's better to learn the new language's natural patterns and idioms.  (contd)

Comment: …This question doesn't give the bigger picture, but there's almost certainy a better approach that doesn't need this sort of dynamic resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMembers

inline fun <reified T: Any> getPropertyByName(instance: T, name: String): Any? {
  return instance::class.declaredMembers.firstOrNull { it.name == name }?.call(instance)
}

// Test:

object SomeObject {
  var a: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf(1, 2, 3)
  var b: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf(9, 8, 7)
}

println(getPropertyByName(SomeObject, "a"))   // Output: [1, 2, 3]
println(getPropertyByName(SomeObject, "b"))   // Output: [9, 8, 7]

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val mySet: MutableSet<Int> = getPropertyByName(SomeObject, "a") as MutableSet<Int>
mySet.add(4)
println(mySet)   // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be directly applicable to your use case, but here are some idiomatic alternatives that do not require dark magic:

```
class MyObject {
    var a: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf("foo")
    var b: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf("bar")
}

val obj = MyObject()

// Get via property reference
val property = MyObject::a
println(property.get(obj))

// Get via lambda that returns the property value
val accessor : MyObject.() -> MutableSet<String> = { a }
println(obj.accessor())
```

In either case, instead of passing around a String holding the name of the property, you'd pass around a piece of code that accesses the property.